# ¿Como unir dos tablas con operación de suma en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo un par de tablas "Switches" y "Storage" relacionadas por el campo "Customers", donde hago una suma en la tabla "Switches" para sacar un total de puertos y hago otro suma en la tabla "Storage" para sacar  el total de capacidad de cada dispositivo. Si ejecuto una consulta a la tabla "Storage" me da el resultado correcto:

```
select sum ("Storage"."UsableCap"), "Customers"."Description" as "Account"
from "Customers"
inner join "Storage"
on "Storage"."Customer" = "Customers"."Id"
where "Storage"."DeviceStatus" = '3674' and "Storage"."Status" = 'A'
GROUP BY "Customers"."Description"
```

[image: Resultado de tabla Storage]

Si agrego al query la consulta para el total de puertos de la "Switches", me arroja un resultado donde la suma de "UsableCap" y "TotalPorts" no coincide, parece que duplica los campos que suma.

```
select
sum ("Storage"."UsableCap"), "Customers"."Description" as "Account",
sum ("Switches"."TotalPorts"::decimal), "Customers"."Description" as "Account"
from "Customers"
inner join "Storage"
on "Storage"."Customer" = "Customers"."Id"
inner join "Switches"
on "Switches"."Customer" = "Customers"."Id"
where
"Storage"."DeviceStatus" = '3674' and "Storage"."Status" = 'A' 
and "Switches"."DeviceStatus" = '3674' and "Switches"."Status" = 'A'
GROUP BY "Customers"."Description"
```

**Resultado de suma incorrecta de los campos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Es dificil responder sin ver el modelo de datos. Aparentemente las tablas "Switches" y "Storage" además de estar vinculada por el campo "Customers" deberían vincularse por el dispositivo (al no incluir a este en el ON del JOIN, se multiplican los join entre ambas tablas (entre distintos dispositivos de un mismo customer todas las combinaciones posibles).

La mejor solución es arreglar el join, pero como no conozco el modelo de datos no lo puedo hacer.

Solución alternativa:

```
SELECT c."Description" as "Account", 
       st."SumUsableCap",
       sw."SumPorts"
FROM "Customers" c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "Customer", SUM("UsableCap") AS "SumUsableCap" FROM "Storage" GROUP BY "Customer" WHERE "DeviceStatus" = '3674' and "Status" = 'A' ) AS st ON st."Customer" = c."Id"
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "Customer", SUM("TotalPorts"::decimal) AS "SumPorts" FROM "Switches" GROUP BY "Customer" WHERE "DeviceStatus" = '3674' and "Status" = 'A') AS sw ON sw."Customer" = c."Id"
ORDER BY c."Description";
```